# What exactly did the mother tell to her daughter in The Purge: Anarchy?

Tags: dialogue, the-purge-anarchy

In *The Purge: Anarchy* there's the following dialogue between the mother and her daughter:

> Mother: They buy poor and sick people and they take them in their homes and they kill them where they're safe.

Is that correct or did she say something else? What did she mean with this?

Comment: I'm not sure what happened here, but if you found an answer to your own question, you can always post the answer yourself (or just delete the question).

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly what she said "It's how the wealthy Purge, baby. They buy poor
and sick people, and they take them in their homes and they kill them
where they're safe."

And She meant that those rich people buy poor people so they can kill without the risk of going outside their homes (safe for the rich people).